# React HIghcharts load event update issues

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to use different markers per category given a dataset. The amount and names of the categories is unknown and can change.

The point update seems to work but the chart is not re-rendered, forcing a manual refresh before showing the right symbols.

So far what I have is:

```
const hcSymbols = ['circle', 'square', 'diamond', 'triangle'];
export const scatterOptions = (measurement_data, ll, ul) => ({
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    events: {
      load: function () {
        const chart = this,
          data = chart.series[0].data;
        const categoryToSymbol = {};
        data.forEach((element) => {
          if (!categoryToSymbol[element.cavity]) {
            categoryToSymbol[element.cavity] = hcSymbols.shift();
          }
          element.update({
            marker: {
              symbol: categoryToSymbol[element.cavity]
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Then this scatterOptions is used in the Highcharts render:

```
const optionsScatter = scatterOptions(measurement_data, ll, ul); //measurement_data is read via an axios hook
....

<HighchartsReact ref={scatterHC} highcharts={Highcharts} options={optionsScatter} />
```

It kind of works, but only after a manual reload. At the first render, all data points have the standard symbol, then simply pressing F5 all the points have the correct category symbol.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @Hyn, I've tried to reproduce the problem but didn't provide enough code. Here you can find a working example with different marker symbols: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-zz4d78?file=/demo.jsx